# Flow of electrons DNMT

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

In a paper about the modes of action of DNMT, it said there an increased flow of electrons to carbon 5 following the formation of a covalent bond between DNMT and carbon 6 on cystine. Why is this? What is the effect of the flow of electrons?

Comment: Why do you think there is?

Comment: Said in a research article about the mode of action of DNMT

Comment: Then put something about this in your question to show that you have thought about it and are asking the community for more information, not to do your homework for you.